# Is revtex4-2 compatible with arXiv?

Tags: revtex, arxiv

I want to submit a preprint to arXiv. I have read that arXiv often uses slightly older versions of TeXLive. Is `revtex4-2` compatible with arXiv, in November 2021?

If not, is `revtex4` compatible?

Comment: arXiv runs under TeXLive 2020, so there should be no problem with `revtex4-2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Y E S.

The arXiv version of the `revtex4-2` package is the one dated slightly earlier than the official release. As I recall, there were some papers that failed to compile with it in our testing or where the differences were enough that there was data lost.